# Node "save" master password for 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using https://github.com/buttercup/buttercup-core on a CLI application. I want to prompt the user to type in the `master password` once, and then store/cache it for 5min so if you constantly run the CLI, it does not re-ask you for your password, similar to `sudo` and how you are not prompted again for 5min.

This is a CLI, so the password needs to persist between processes that run.

Comment: What's your threat model?

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to store a salted hash of the password within a file somewhere that your CLI keeps track of. You can check the stored hash against the hash of the correct password every time you need to prompt the user for the password but don't want to directly.

This solves your need for cross-process password checking as well.

Comment: A timestamp should also be stored along side the hashed password so that the "5min" expiration can be enforced.